# Stat with Python about line count of 2-bits

Tags: python, stat

Pseudocode to get amount of lines for 2-bit system (2*30=60):

```
python -c "from math import ceil; print ceil(`stat --printf="%s/30"`/500.0)";
```

but I would like to really run similar stat command within Python itself because now there two processes. 
The code does not work, I think, because the `printf` give STRING
which prints `ceil(24152000/30)`.

How can you combine do such statistics with Python as one-liner?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What do you mean by “count of 2-bits”? What is your command supposed to do — I can't think of a system where this doesn't produce an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  The following prints the stats (?) for the files given as arguments:

```
perl -MPOSIX=ceil -E 'say ceil((-s)/15000.0) for(@ARGV)' *.dat
```

Doing the same with a single line of Python is possible, but it's better avoided. :)

Comment: There must exists some single way for this. Probably, defining some variable first and doing this can be easier. This Perl liner is not so intuitive.